# Using arrays across multiple classes in C# and insertion sort won't work

Tags: c#, arrays, insertion-sort

I'm working on an assignment for class in which I need to use an insertion sort on an unsorted array, but it won't quite work. The algorithms i sued for the sorts either changed all values to 0 or all to the last value (96) with a 0 on top.
Code for the array class

```
using System;

namespace UnorderedArrayListNamespace
{
public class UnorderedArrayList
{
    public int[] list;
    protected int next;
   // protected int Count;

    public UnorderedArrayList()
    {
        list = new int[100];
        next = 0;
    }



    public void insert(ref int item)
    {
        list[next] = item;
        next++;
    }

    public void remove(ref int item)
    {
        if (next == 0)
        {
        }
        else
        {
        //find value, if it exists
            for (int i = 0; i < next; i++)
            {
                if (item.Equals(list[i]))
                {
                    for (int j = i; j < next; j++) list[j] = list[j + 1];
                    next--;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void removeAll(ref int item)
    {

    }

    public int[] InsertionSort(ref int item)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j > 0; j--)
            {
                if (list[j - 1] > list[j])
                {
                    int temp = list[j - 1];
                    list[j - 1] = list[j];
                    list[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        return list;

    }

    public void Minmax(ref int item)
    {
        int  min , max;
        min = list[0];
        max = list[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < list.Length; i++)
        {
            if (min > list[i])
                min = list[i];
            if (max < list[i])
                max = list[i];
        }
        Console.WriteLine("min:" + min);
        Console.WriteLine("max:" + max);
    }
    public void print()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < next; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(list[i]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
 }

}
```

Code for main class

```
namespace ConsoleApp3
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        UnorderedArrayList u = new UnorderedArrayList();

        u.print();
        int var = 7;
        u.insert(ref var);
        var = 12;
        u.insert(ref var);
        var = 5;
        u.insert(ref var);
        var = 5;
        u.insert(ref var);
        var = 5;
        u.insert(ref var);
        var = 96;
        u.insert(ref var);
        u.print();
        var = 5;
        u.remove(ref var);
        u.print();
        u.InsertionSort(ref var);
        u.print();
        u.Minmax(ref var);      
    }  
  }
}
```

Updated to include all parts of the Array Class. I'm sorry if this is too long winded, it's my first post and I wanted to be thorough.

upon comment request here's the assignment:

Modify the supplied class UnorderedArrayList the following ways:

a.  the method remove() removes an element from the list by shifting the elements of the list.  However, if the element to be removed is at the beginning of the list and the list is fairly large, it could take a lot of computer time to perform the operation.  Because the list elements are in no particular order, you could simply remove the element by copying the last element in the list at the position of the item to be removed and reducing the length of the list.

b.  the method remove removes only the first occurrence of an element.  Add the method removeAll() that will remove all occurrences of a given element.

c.  add the methods min() and max() which will return the smallest and largest respective elements in the list

d.  add an insertion sort method that puts the list in order.

e.  write a Main() method that thoroughly tests these modifications and demonstrates correctness.

Comment: Did you step through the code with a debugger?

Comment: In your `InsertionSort` method you don't use 'item' parameter but only sort it.
You need to insert 'item' where you should (find the sorted position, add it to the loop).

Comment: I am getting the feeling you are mixing 2 sorting algorithms. Can you post the assignment so we better understand what needs to be done?

Comment: @Aldert posted the assignment, hope it helps.

Comment: I have a look at it. Normally sorting a list and inserting an object in a list so it is still sorted are two different actions. This is because you only need to sort once. Weird this is put together in the assignment.

Comment: Can you please update and show all code you have so far. I am confused as to what has been given to you as a start and what yo have done so far. It is not the intent that people on stackoverflow do the assignments. I have no problem helping you but I need to understand what you ahve done so far.

Comment: @Aldert I've updated the code to include everything so far. The things I have had to do myself are: the remove all, the min/max (you can ignore these two), and the insertion sort. Everything else is what was given to me as a starter. I don't expect/want the people here to just do the assignment for me, but I do greatly appreciate you taking time to help me along on this.

Comment: OK, now we are talking, this I can use. I have a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are. in the InsertionSort I first added the item and then did the sort. The minimum is the first item in the list once it is sorted and the maximum the last item. Your MinMax logic was good but just wanted to make you aware once sorted, it is easy to get min,max.

Have a good look at the sorting and how this is done, write down the numbers in the order or the unsorterlist and write down where they change places. This help you understand the logic. Important, you have i & j, both representing the position of items to compare.

7-12- 5- 5-96-5

5-12- 5- 5-96-7 (7 & 5 switched)

5- 5-12- 5-96-7 (12 & 5 switched) etc.

Also, removeAll is same code without the break..

using System;

```
namespace UnorderedArrayListNamespace
{
    public class UnorderedArrayList
    {
        public int[] list;
        protected int next;
        // protected int Count;

        public UnorderedArrayList()
        {
            list = new int[100];
            next = 0;
        }



        public void insert(ref int item)
        {
            list[next] = item;
            next++;
        }

        public void remove(ref int item)
        {
            //find value, if it exists
            for (int i = 0; i < next; i++)
            {
                if (item.Equals(list[i]))
                {
                    list[i] = list[next - 1];  //Move last item to empty slot
                    next--;
                    break; //break because we only remove first
                }
            }

        }

        public void removeAll(ref int item)
        {
            //find value, if it exists
            for (int i = 0; i < next; i++)
            {
                if (item.Equals(list[i]))
                {
                    list[i] = list[next - 1];  //Move last item to empty slot
                    next--;
                }
            }
        }

        public int[] InsertionSort(ref int item)
        {
            //First we add the item
            insert(ref item);

            for (int i = 0; i < next - 2; i++)
            {
                for (int j = next - 1; j > i; j--)
                {
                    if (list[i] > list[j])
                    {
                        int temp = list[j];
                        list[j] = list[i];
                        list[i] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
            return list;

        }

        public int Min()
        {
            if (next == 0) throw new Exception("No element is list, cannot get minimum");
            return list[0];
        }
        public int Max()
        {
            if (next == 0) throw new Exception("No element is list, cannot get maximun");
            return list[next - 1];
        }



        public void print()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < next; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("{0} ", list[i]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            UnorderedArrayList u = new UnorderedArrayList();

            u.print();
            int var = 7;
            u.insert(ref var);
            var = 12;
            u.insert(ref var);
            var = 5;
            u.insert(ref var);
            var = 5;
            u.insert(ref var);
            var = 5;
            u.insert(ref var);
            var = 96;
            u.insert(ref var);
            u.print();
            var = 5;
            u.remove(ref var);
            u.print();
            u.InsertionSort(ref var);
            u.print();

        Console.WriteLine("Minimum of sortedlist is {0}", u.Min());
        Console.WriteLine("Maximum of sortedlist is {0}", u.Max());

        u.removeAll(ref var);
        u.print();
        Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is honestly a lot more than i was expecting you to do. Thank you very much for you help, I really do appreciate it.

Comment: You are welcome. When you like programming, have a look at Binarysorting/searching. Good algorithms which are very fast. The standard List object of C# is also using this.